# WKWebView not responding to long click

Tags: html, objective-c, select, wkwebview, long-click

I have a reader on which I was using `UIWebView` to display `HTML` content, similar to the kobo and `iBooks`.

I am transitioning now to `WKWebView` as it seems that `UIWebView` is deprecated.

I am facing the problem that `WKWebView` doesn't recognize at all the long touch gesture and no selection is showing. While this problem didn't show using the `UIWebView`.

This is how I'm implementing `WKWebView`:

```
WKWebViewConfiguration *theConfiguration = [[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc] init];
theConfiguration.selectionGranularity = WKSelectionGranularityCharacter;

readWKWebView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame configuration:theConfiguration];
readWKWebView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
readWKWebView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = true;
readWKWebView.multipleTouchEnabled = true;

[self.view addSubview:readWKWebView];
readWKWebView.userInteractionEnabled = true;
readWKWebView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

[readWKWebView loadFileURL:htmlPathURL allowingReadAccessToURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:stringOfAllwedPath]];
[readWKWebView loadHTMLString:loadString baseURL:baseURL];
```

I do inject the following css in the `HTML`:

```
html {
    height:730px;
    font-size:24px;
    width:100%;
}

body {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    width:100%;
}

#viewer {
    width:668px; 
    height:730px;
}

#book {
    width:668px;
    height:730px;
    margin-left:50px;
    margin-right:50px;
    -webkit-column-count:auto;
    -webkit-column-width:668px;
    -webkit-column-gap:100px;
    text-align:right;
}

.h {
    margin-top:220px;
}
```

Any idea what could be the reason behind absence of selection feature?

Comment: What are you trying to Use long press on? Email? or a link? also could you attach your HTML page

Comment: for selection, I need to select text from the webview to allow highlight and other features

Answer (score 0):

In fact the problem wasn't with the selection itself, but seems that WKWebView unlike UIWebView does not respond to gesture while having a layer on top of it. so on bringing it to front the problem was resolved.

```
WKWebViewConfiguration *theConfiguration = [[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc] init];
theConfiguration.selectionGranularity = WKSelectionGranularityCharacter;

WKWebView *myWkWebview = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame configuration:theConfiguration];
[self.view addSubview: myWkWebview];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:myWkWebview];
```